# HTTP query interrupted on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, webforms, internet-explorer-11

I was assigned some debugging to do on an existing ASP.NET WebForms application that uses a lot of UpdatePanels.
One of the button launches some tasks that are very long to perform, and it is expected.

The problem is that we have a strange behavior : on Internet Explorer, the query stops exactly 5 minutes after it started with the following error :

On IE11 with enterprise mode enabled (simulates IE8) (the website uses Enterprise Mode):

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 12019

On native IE11 :

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 0

So the update panel is not refreshed, but I see that even if the query failed, the server continues to perform the tasks (writes to the database), so it's not a server timeout.
Moreover, if I perform the same action locally, on the IIS server, the query isn't interrupted.

What baffles me is that it works without any issue with Chrome (the query we're testing lasts 6 minutes)

I read a lot of things on the Internet but nothing that helps, to my knowledge we don't have a load balancer (this error seem to appear mostly with reports behind a load balancer).
I looked for all the timeouts I can (server and client side), and increased all the values to ridiculous amounts, no effect.
I tried to apply the changes to the registry as [explained here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explor), without success.

I tried with Fiddler, but not sure how to interpret its results and both on IE and Chrome, 5 minutes after the start of the query I get an HTTP 401 error and it asks for an authentication (we're using Windows authentication). That only happens when using Fiddler, no authentication is asked usually.
Not sure what to do with that :). Again, Chrome seems to handle it without problem.

I don't have any more ideas...
I suspect that it's a company proxy issue but I don't understand why it works with Chrome, and it might be complicated to ask for configuration changes on the proxy, I need to be absolutely sure it's that, I don't know how.

Any idea/suggestion?